# Fire event till touched android

Tags: android

I want to increase the width of a line dynamically as long as the user touches the screen. I used the following code :-

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        stopX++; 

    }
    return true;//EDITED (FORGOT TO PASTE THIS LINE)
}
```

I make the line from 0 to `stopX` and y-axis is constant as long as the screen is touched. But, I failed. The line increases *in width(as required)*. **BUT**, the line increases in width only when the screen is touched, i.e., when I touch the screen, the line increases by 1 BUT THE GROWTH DOES NOT CONTINUE AS LONG AS I TOUCH IT. I hope that I was able to make you understand my problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is fired once when you touch the View. You will need it for e.g. to start a loop that increments `stopX` in event `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and stop it in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. For e.g.:

```
Thread t;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      t=new Thread(new Runnable(){
       @Override run(){
        while(true){
         try{
          stopX++;
          Thread.sleep(500);
         }catch(ThreadInterruptedException e){
          break;
         }
       }

    }
  });
         t.start(); 

     }
    return true;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    t.interrupt();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is it giving exceptions? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this (just make sure to add the relevant lock where needed in order to keep the m_Task safe).
I would also consider running the task with a timer in order to prevent some busy waiting.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // Start an async task
        // Add a lock
        m_Task = new LineIncreamentTask(...);
        task.Start();    
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // Cancel the task
        // Add a lock
        if (m_Task != null) m_Task.cancel();
    }
    return true;//EDITED (FORGOT TO PASTE THIS LINE)
}

private class LineIncreamentTask
{
     public void doInBackground(...)
     {
           // Increase the line width
           // Update the UI & whatever
     }

     public void onPostExecute(...)
     {
         if (!isCanceled())
         {
               // Add a lock
               // Consider using a timer to prevent busy waiting
               m_Task = new LineIncreamentTask(...);
               m_Task.start();
         }
     }
}
```